# Prove a series converges uniformly

Tags: uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I was having trouble with this question

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{2^n}$$   on $D(0,1.5)$

I get you have to use the $M$-test but how would you go about doing that, any help would be so greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|<\frac32$, then $\left|\frac z2\right|<\frac34$. So $\left|\frac z2\right|^n<\left(\frac34\right)^n$, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Since the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac34\right)^n$ converges, it follows from the $M$-test that your series converges uniformly.

Comment: thanks Jose so much, that explanation was so much simpler than all the lecture notes I've done , so for a full proof I would just have to show that the (3/4)^n converges right?

Comment: @Elena We have to shoe that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac34\right)^n$ converges.

Comment: Thanks for the help, one last question sorry. Say I wanted to now calculate the series  \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/2^n   what would I do

Comment: That's a different question. Please post it as such. But I must say that I don't understand your question.

Comment: sure I'll post it now